# Find element in a collection and return it along with its index

Tags: kotlin

I want to search through a collection and find the first item that matches a criteria and then returns the item as well as the item's index in the collection. The only solution I can think of is to first use the find method and then use the indexOfFirst method to perform a second search.

But that results in searching the collection twice, which I want to avoid. Of course I could just loop through the collection and find the item and break from it once I find the item and I have both the item and its index. But that is somewhat slower than native Kotlin functions.

Is there a single function in Kotlin that can do both?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if there is a single function that returns both, but if you look at `indexOfFirst`  for example:

```
public inline fun <T> List<T>.indexOfFirst(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Int {
    var index = 0
    for (item in this) {
        if (predicate(item))
            return index
        index++
    }
    return -1
}
```

You can change it a bit so it will return a `Pair<Int,T>?` for example:

```
 inline fun <T> List<T>.indexAndValueOfFirst(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Pair<Int, T>? {
     var index = 0
     for (item in this) {
         if (predicate(item))
             return Pair(index, item)
         index++
     }
     return null
 }
```

now you can use it as:

```
val l = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
 
val x = l.indexAndValueOfFirst { it == "6" } // null
val y = l.indexAndValueOfFirst { it == "1" } // (0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Ben Shmuel's answer is very reasonable. You can kinda do this in a single function with [`foldIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold-indexed.html) but that will iterate the entire collection, past a the matching element.

```kotlin
fun <T> Iterable<T>.findWithIndex(match: (T) -> Boolean): Pair<Int, T?> =
    foldIndexed(Pair(-1, null as T)) { i, result, value -> 
        if (match(value)) Pair(i, value) else result 
    }


fun main() {
    val data = List(100) { it * 2 }
    data.findWithIndex { it == 50 }.also { println(it) }   // (25, 50)
    data.findWithIndex { it == 500 }.also { println(it) }  // (-1, null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't

```kotlin
fun <T> List<T>.firstIndexed(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Pair<Int, T> {
    return asSequence().mapIndexed(::Pair).first { (_, v) -> predicate(v) }
}

fun <T> List<T>.firstIndexedOrNull(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Pair<Int, T>? {
    return asSequence().mapIndexed(::Pair).firstOrNull { (_, v) -> predicate(v) }
}
```

Use it as

```kotlin
val list = listOf(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)
println(list.firstIndexed { v -> v < 5 })    // output: (0, 2)
println(list.firstIndexed { v -> v > 10 })   // output: (5, 12)
println(list.firstIndexed { v -> v < 0 })    // throws: NoSuchElementException

println(list.firstIndexedOrNull { v -> v < 5 })    // output: (0, 2)
println(list.firstIndexedOrNull { v -> v > 10 })   // output: (5, 12)
println(list.firstIndexedOrNull { v -> v < 0 })    // output: null
```